# DataGrid set column width programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, dataset

I have the following piece of code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var src1 = Page.DataContext.ExtranetTypes;
    var res1 = from row in src1 select row;

    var src2 = Page.DataContext.ExtranetDocuments;
    var res2 = from row in src2 select row;

    var query = from r1 in res1
                join r2 in res2 on r1.ID equals r2.FileTypeID
                select new { r2.PublicationDate, Title = r2.Title, Type = r1.Title };

    DocumentGrid.DataSource = query;
    DocumentGrid.DataBind();
}
```

I'd like to set the width of the columns, but I can't set the width for each column because the query has not executed yet.

```
DocumentGrid.Columns[1].ControlStyle.Width
```

Gives an error, because the columns is calculated when the query is excecuted, and it's executed at the latest moment possible because of late binding. Is there any way I can set the width of these columns?

Comment: take a look at here http://odetocode.com/articles/218.aspx

Comment: Use BoundField columns instead of autogenerated columns.

Answer (score 1):

A datagrid or gridview is generated when the datasource has some thing to display. If there nothing to display then the grid is not rendered on the page. But if you want to display the grid in case of no data , then add a skeleton datatable or list, to render the grid and then your code will work. Also if you paste the HTML of the grid, it would be a greate help

Answer (score 0):

I used BoundFields as suggested by one of the comments to my question.

result:

```
<asp:GridView ID="DocumentGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Publication Date" DataField="PublicationDate" ItemStyle-Width="120px"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Title" DataField="Title" ItemStyle-Width="400px"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Type" DataField="Type" ItemStyle-Width="100px"/>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Just be sure to set autogenerate columns to false, otherwise you'll get extra columns.

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
DocumentGrid.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

then you can set Width programatically. This because query.ToList() commits the data and makes them readable by DocumentGrid.DataSource property.

Comment: it will not solve the problem, asd he's asking to increase width

Comment: After query.ToList() command, he can set Width programatically.